# Print RECORDS in between from_date to to_date in odoo report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

How to print the records from a particular date to a particular date in odoo?

Comment: Hi, please never include "solved" in your title. The green checkmark is enough.

Comment: Roger that!!!@Cœur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line to your render html by calling the fields from the python file: 
Declare this after the class

```
report_id = self.env['your_object_name'].search([('id','=',docids)])


            any_name = self.env['your_model_name'].search([('date', '>=', report_id.date_from), ('date', '<=', report_id.date_to), ('name', '=', report_id.name.id)])
```